# Passing openssl signature to php script

Tags: php, openssl

Because of some platform limitation I'm forced to generate openssl signature in command line. I'm executing openssl sign command and with openssl verify command it validates. But when I tired to sign by command and validate by php, it fails.

```
$filesize = filesize('test.txt');
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'rb');
$data = fread($fp, $filesize);

$prvKey = 'qa_sig_ec.key'; 

$command = 'echo -n "'.$data.'" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign '. $prvKey;
$sig = exec($command);

$filesize2 = filesize(__DIR__."\qa_sig_ec.pub");
$fp2 = fopen(__DIR__."\qa_sig_ec.pub", 'rb');
$publicKey = fread($fp2, $filesize2);

var_dump(openssl_verify($data, $sig, $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256));
```

I believe that is something wrong with signature passing, because openssl command generates binary content, and perhpas when i pass it to script, it just break.
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can base64 encode openssl signatures for textwise comparison and transmission.

You can *probably*:

```
$command = 'echo -n "'.$data.'" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign '. $prvKey. ' | base64';
```

in php. I've also had trouble using php's openssl commands with key resources. It seems to be more reliable to:

```
file_get_contents($keypath);
```

And feed openssl functions the string containing the key. I haven't tried this with a passphrase protected key. Try this if using key resources doesn't work. base64 decode the signature to feed it to openssl functions in binary if it doesn't digest the encoded string version.

My answer is based on experience using php's openssl functions to verify openssl generated signatures. I haven't tried to do *exactly* what you're doing but I have a hunch your issues can be solved with strategic base64 encoding/decoding. It should take literally a minute to try for you.